# Converting a String from a Web Form to MongoMapper Model with Array Datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I have a MongoMapper model and am trying to convert a comma-delimited string into an Array to be stored.

The main problem is that a string such as `tags = "first,second,third"` is not getting converted to an array in the database like `["first","second","third"]`. Instead it is going in as `["first,second,third"]`.

There are some other strange things going on as well: 
  1) In preen_tags I have to include the unless tags.nil? after every line
  2) in preen_tags, using the debugger `tags` returns nil

Here is my model

```
class Template
  include MongoMapper::Document
  validate :validate_tags
  after_validation :preen_tags

  key :template_id,     ObjectId

  key :title,           String
  key :description,     String

  key :tags,            Array

  timestamps!

  def validate_tags
    errors.add_to_base "You Must Enter At Least 1 Tag." if tags.blank? 
  end


  def preen_tags
    #return if tags.nil?     #why doesn't this work??
    #only alphanumeric chars allowed, except hyphens and commas
    tags = tags[0] if tags.is_a?(Array)
    tags = tags.gsub(/[^0-9a-z\-\,]/i, '') unless tags.nil?
    #convert spaces to hyphens
    tags = tags.gsub(/\s/, '-') unless tags.nil?
    tags = tags.split(",") unless tags.nil?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like converting the String to an Array inside the controller before passing it to the Model has solved things.

Answer (score 0):

it's because by default tags is an Array in MongoMapper like you define it. So you can try `tags.empty?` instead of `tags.nil?`

In last case tags becomes nil because you try get first element of tags, but there are no one inside. Just nil. You tags becomes nil.

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't my main problem though. I updated the question to be more clear.
Also, by the time preen_tags is called, according to the debugger, tags is indeed nil.